# The Anagrammy... what?

Tags: riddle, visual, steganography, anagram, acronym

> Hello, did you hear about the Anagrammy Contest? No, wait — the anagrammy competition... or the anagrammy tournament? Look, I don't remember what it's called, exactly. Great, isn't it? >:(
>
> It occurs every month, where a quote is given to the competitors in which they must find an anagram of it. Soon, once the month is over, the best one is announced and wins, though nobody knows who the judges are... but at least I know what the quote was this month:
>
> > ```
> > "We are looking at a society increasingly dependent on machines, yet decreasingly capable of making or even using them effectively." — Douglas Rushkoff.
> > ```
>
> This is what I anagrammed. Entries must be emailed to **anagrammy.**$[\qquad]$***@grammail.***${}$**com**. However, regarding my anagram entry, I don't know what goes in the empty square bracket (there isn't actually a square bracket in the email; rather, it is only my notation to emphasise that I don't know what that part of the email actually is, since I don't remember the specific name of this anagrammy event, whether it be the anagrammy *contest* or *competition* or *tournament*, or maybe even *match* or *game*?)
>
> Wait, I know there is some kind of constraint in my anagram that reveals what this anagrammy event is actually called...but I don't even remember what that is, too. Dammit! Oh, and today is the last day of the month, which means... my anagram needs to be emailed by the end of tonight!! Right, here is my anagram of the quote:
>
> > ```
> >     Anyone creating fresh,
> >     New technology
> >     And updating my
> >     Gadget lives to sickly
> >     Ruin - loads of
> >     Areas feel safe if
> >     Mine can be
> >     More cognitive.
> >     Yuck! Seek help!
> > ```
>
> <sup><sub>Posted to the $Puzz\ell$$ing\;Stack\;Exchange$.</sub></sup>

Can you help this *character* know what the rest of the email might be, through their anagram? He or she, gender doesn't matter. Also, the text part of the y*ell*ow sandbox (except the quote and anagram of it) can help you to solve the puzzle...w*ell*, that is to say the *least* ;)

---

A whole day and no answers? That's rare for my kind of puzzles! Ok, let's get straight to the hint:

**Hint 1:**

> Every competitor wants to come first in the big anagrammy event... perhaps you too would like to see what comes first, but that is, if you are interested in letters.

Oh, and one last thing:

> We didn't submit the anagram yesterday, so theoretically, the aim of this puzzle is kind of over... lucky it's April Fools though! You can work on this puzzle for as long as you like! And no, this part isn't actually a hint.

Comment: P.S. If you have found the answer, then it might be a bit difficult to show it in a picture, but I can actually help with that, lest you need it :)

Comment: All I noticed was that rot13(V pbhyq znxr 'n tveyvfu vqvbgvp juvar' sebz nyy gur pncvgny yrggref)

Comment: @Smock oh, you are definitely on the right track! (ROT13) Gel gb nantenz gur pncvgny yrggref frcnengryl va rnpu cnentencu... ohg bayl gur barf gung jbhyq zngpu jvgu gur gur svefg uvag.

Comment: rot13 (pynfuvat gur jbeq) ?

Comment: @Smock no... oh, close! There are two paragraphs above the quote, by the way ;)

Comment: I tried that but only got rot13("UNPAYT" VF GUR JBEQ ohg pbhyqa'g znxr nalguvat sebz gung svefg frg bs yrggref) discounting I's as they seem to be everywhere else - but even with one, it was still gibberish. by the way the other bit at the bottom I think might be rot13(yrneare)

Comment: @Smock you can't make anything from rot13(UNPAYT), hence you need something extra. I believe that bit at the bottom of which you might be referring to can give you what you need... hope I'm not giving away too much, here, but eh.

Comment: and apparently you are, by the look of hexomino's answer ;) +1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's called the

> Anagrammy Challenge

Reasoning 1

> It's hidden vertically within OP's anagram
>
> ```
> Anyone creating fresh,
> New technology
> And updating my
> Gadget lives to sickly
> Ruin - loads of
> Areas feel safe if
> Mine can be
> More cognitive.
> Yuck! Seek help!
> ```

Reasoning 2

> If we take the capital letters (not including I) of the sentences in each of the 1st, 2nd, 3rd and 4th paragraphs respectively we have 
>  HACNLG/IS/TEH/WDOR. 
>  This almost anagrams to four separate words - CHALNG IS THE WORD 
>  However, the string **ell** is highlighted at least three times in the puzzle - First as the "l" in Puzzling Stack Exchange, then also in the words "yellow" and "well" below the yellow box. 
>  This could indicate the additional letters we need to make the word "challenge". 
>  However, what we really would need is "eel". This is not an error but indicates we still need to extract an extra clue from the puzzle. As explained by the OP, we need to interpret the em-dash and the string ">:(" in the first paragraph as cluing the process of removing a letter and adding and 'e' to "ell", respectively. Converting ">:(" to "add an e" is not an obvious step, the ">" implies the addition and the "(" is above "9" on the keyboard which is a backwards "e". These two steps allows us to go from "ell" $\rightarrow$ "eel" and retrieve the letters required to complete the "challenge".

Comment: Close, you are also on the right track. (ROT13) Lbh unir gnxra gur evtug nccebnpu va trggvat gur svefg yrggref... ohg bayl gb fgneg fragraprf. Jung nobhg gur svefg yrggref bs anzrf? V zrna, jul vf "Nantenzzl Pbagrfg" jvgu pncvgnyf N naq P ohg abg "nantenzzl pbzcrgvgvba" naq rgp? Nyfb, abgvpr gung gur svefg jbeq jevggra vf "Uryyb" :Q

Comment: Oh, and congrats on finding rot13(gur bqq yrggre bhg va "Chmmyvat Fgnpx Rkpunatr")! Very clever! :D

Comment: @user477343 I think I'm getting closer, updated my answer.

Comment: I think you've cracked it!

Comment: Looked at it, and nicely done. You kind of skipped a step, actually. (ROT13) Gur svefg cnentencu unf na rz qnfu, juvpu ybbxf yvxr gur zvahf fvta (vaqvpngvat n yrggre vf gnxra bhg). Naq gura jr unir gur snpr ">:(" jurer gur fvta ">" vf yvxr na neebj cbvagvat gb "(" juvpu vf ba gur "9" xrl. Guvf vf npghnyyl na "r" onpx gb sebag. Fb abj lbh unir na rkgen "r" naq n yrggre gung lbh zhfg gnxr sebz "ryy". Ubjrire, lbh unir fxvccrq guvf fgrc naq whfg jrag gb gur nafjre: "rry", naq gura gb gur npghny jbeq lbh sbhaq!

Comment: Oh, and since $9=3\times 3$ then that's why rot13("ryy" vf uvtuyvtugrq 3 gvzrf va gur chmmyr), in case you were wondering. But with my previous comment being said, and with what @Smock said, you have cracked it! Find the word in the anagram! If you can't, there are other hints scattered around... ;) well done!

Comment: @user477343 Okay, I don't think I would ever have gotten that explanation, I'll add to the answer for clarification and completelness.

Comment: *Puzzling* members crack everything, so I made this explanation real obscure, and was actually gonna put it in Hint 2 or Hint 3. You made it before then, though :P

Comment: Last part so you can get the tick (and maybe a bounty, if you want, because you appear to have found this *challenging* hehe): how does the answer appear in the anagram? :)

Comment: @user477343 Oh my goodness, I've just seen what you mean. Can't believe I missed that before, thanks.

Comment: Congratulations! $\color{green}{\checkmark}$

Answer (score 1):

All I noticed was that

> The first letters of the anagram spell ANAGRAMMY; I was thinking that the competition could be therefore the Anagrammy Acrostic or something to fit the constraints but couldn’t back this up with anything substantive.

Comment: No, that is only the first part of it; the event is called the *Anagrammy* $[$ *something-something* $]$. Still, your answer does make sense, so... $(+1)$!